# get git username to link to profile

Tags: git, github

When a user commits to a repository I usually see

"git commit message" [username]

[username] usually links to the persons github profile

when I do it, my usename is my username on my computer.

How do I get it to be my github username.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The email address you have used is different than that of your github's account. If you use the same email address, i think it will link up.

To change the email address:

```
git config --global user.email <your@emailaddress>
```

If you want it for a specific project remove the '--global' option.

Answer (score 4):

You need to [correctly setup your Git configuration](http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/) so the email matches the one associated with your GitHub account:

> Set your username and email. Git tracks who makes each commit by
>   checking the user’s name and email. In addition, we use this info to
>   associate your commits with your GitHub account. To set these, enter
>   the code below, replacing the name and email with your own. The name
>   should be your actual name, not your GitHub username.
>
> ```
> $ git config --global user.name "Firstname Lastname"
> $ git config --global user.email "your_email@youremail.com"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you followed the steps here: http://help.github.com/set-your-user-name-email-and-github-token/

I believe the following steps at the end of the document is what's important in linking to your github account:

$ git config --global github.user username

$ git config --global github.token 0123456789yourf0123456789token

Comment: Nope, those values are for local apps to authenticate, nothing else.